# Rank of a graph in matroid theory

Tags: graphs, matroids, rank

I was going through the concept of graphs as matroids and I came upon the rank of a graph. Wikipedia lists it as $n - c$, $n = |V|$, $c =$ # of connected components.

I do understand rank and nullity of matrices, and graphs when expressed in their incidence matrix form have a one-to-one correspondence with the rank of its incidence matrix.
However, I am not understanding how
$r(G) = |V| - c$, $c = $ # of connected components
and the definition of rank as the maximum size of a subforest of $G$ are equivalent.

I tried looking it up online but found no satisfactory explanation. Any resources that would be helpful to understand the concept would be great.

Comment: Are you familiar with the definitions of (i) rank of a matroid, (ii) graphical matroid?

Comment: The rank of a graphical matroid is the maximum number of edges which do not close a cycle. In a connected component of size $m$, the maximum number of edges which do not close a cycle is $m - 1$. Summing this over all connected components gives $n - c$.

Comment: Thanks for this. This view of summing over all connected components makes everything clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of a graphical matroid is the size of a spanning forest, which consists of a spanning tree in each connected component. A spanning tree for a connected component of size $m$ contains $m - 1$ edges. Summing this over all connected components, we see that a spanning forest contains $n - c$ edges.